# Document Similarity with User Preference

Tags: similarity, tfidf, cosine-distance, similar-documents, semantic-similarity

To measure the similarity between two documents, one can use, e.g. TF-IDF/Cosine Similarity. Supposing that after calculating the similarity scores of `Doc A` against a list of Documents (`Doc B`, `Doc C`,...), we got:

| Document Pair | Similarity Score |
| --- | --- |
| Doc A vs. Doc B | 0.45 |
| Doc A vs. Doc C | 0.30 |
| Doc A vs. ... | ... |

Of course, `Doc B` seems to be the closest one, in terms of similarity, for `Doc A`. But what if Users, as humans, think `Doc C` *should* be chosen as the closest? That said, how can we factor in the User Preference, so that later if the Users run the algorithm again, the score of `Doc A vs. Doc C` will be higher than `Doc A vs. Doc B`? Put it simply, beside the calculation of TF-IDF/Cosine Similarity, the algorithm also takes into account the User's history of choices, and suggests the `Doc` that satisfies *that specific User* the most.

I'm open to any techniques, apart from TF-IDF/Cosine Similarity. It would be great if there were also some readily available implementation, e.g. in Python.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different things:

- document similarity is based only on the documents
- previous users choices can be used to train a recommender system, or simply applied in a rule-based fashion.

The two can be combined in a user-specific recommender system, but mind that the choices of the users are not necessarily consistent, not even for a single user. This is why it cannot be assumed that the selected choices mean "more similar documents".